# Load event and frame location change

Tags: javascript

Having following code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#ifrm').load(function() {
    try {               
      window.document.domain = "sub_domain.domain";

      document.getElementById("ifrm");  // 1
      console.log("bla");
      document.getElementById("ifrm").id = "new_ifrm";  // 2
      window.frames[0].location = "http://server_2.sub_domain.domain/.../iframe_2.html";
    } 
    catch (e) {
      console.log("exception!");
      alert("Error: " + e);
    }
  });             
});
...
<body>
        <iframe src="http://server_2.sub_domain.domain/.../iframe_1.html" id="ifrm" style="height: 100px"></iframe>
    </body>
```

1.) In the #2 line I'm changing the frame id and in the next line I'm loading the new content to the frame now with NEW id. 
The output is like so:

```
bla
bla
exception! (TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null)
```

The question is why does the "load" event is fired once again after changing the id if the frame id isn't now "ifrm" but "new_ifrm"?

2.) If the line #1 causes an exception (document.getElementById(...) is null) why does the "bla" is outputted? Shouldn't the exception immediately direct the execution to "catch" block ignoring anything below the exception line (#1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is why does the "load" event is fired once again after changing the id if the frame id isn't now "ifrm" but "new_ifrm"?

The event handler is bound to the iframe itself.

The ID is only used at the time you call `getElementById`.

> If the line #1 causes an exception

It doesn't.

Calling a function that returns a `null` value is fine.

`document.getElementById("ifrm").id = "new_ifrm";` throws the exception when you try to create a property on a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

> why does the "load" event is fired once again after changing the id if the frame id isn't now "ifrm" but "new_ifrm"?

I don't think it is. But it will be when you set the iframe's location: causing it to load content from the new URL.

> If the line #1 causes an exception (document.getElementById(...) is null) why does the "bla" is outputted? Shouldn't the exception immediately direct the execution to "catch" block ignoring anything below the exception line (#1).

The exception isn't because `getElementById(…)` is returning null. It is because you're then referencing a property from it. The exception is being thrown on the line marked 2. (You can confirm this with a stack trace from you're browserss dev tools.)

```
var x = document.getElementById('foo');
```

and `x` will be null. This is fine and useful (tells you there is no such element).

But

```
var t = document.getElementById('foo').id;
```

is not. Because `null` has no properties. So will fail.